# Checkbox For each loop

Tags: php

Can you please look at the code? Where I am wrong?

I have different checkboxes with values as under, what I am trying to do is add the total from previous post name $total+separate integer from the strings,i need the value in checkbox with same as i did so don't worry why i do this.Whatever the user checked the checkboxes values will be added to  $total variable. Foreach loop does not do what I want, I know it iterates the loop and add it. Any alternative solution?

```
  $total=$_POST['total-price']; //prevoius page post
    foreach($_POST["features"] as $checkedValue) {
       echo $checkedValue . "<br />";
       $int = filter_var($checkedValue, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); //seperate integer from string
       $sum= $int + $total;
       echo "final total:\$" .$sum . "<br />";
    }
```

HTML checkboxes:

```
<input id="2" type="checkbox"  onClick="" name="features[]" value="Mobile Development $100"/>
<input id="2" type="checkbox"  onClick="" name="features[]" value="Mobile Development $100"/>
```

Comment: if i have checked 2-3 checkboxes,it is giving wrong result.B/c of iteration of fro each loop

Comment: Related to silly's answer: You should not use double quotes in PHP unless your string includes variables. A double-quoted string in PHP is effectively a function call, and if you're not doing anything with the function you're just wasting performance. -- Also, what is your question? You haven't said what your expected result is, or what you're getting that's different than what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
echo "final total:$" .$sum . "<br>";
```

to

```
echo 'final total:$'.$sum . "<br>";
```

or

```
echo "final total:\$" .$sum . "<br>";
```

Comment: Hehe, yep, that 'escapes' quite a few people after looking at code for hours :)

Comment: thats not a big issue,$ is for dollar sign. :P

Comment: i am not getting waht i want